# VBA, Match Function with Variable as lookup value, quotes/no quotes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following in my vba:

```
WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_value, lookup_range, match_type)
```

For lookup value if I explicitly name the value, ie. 10 (no quotes). It works.

```
WorksheetFunction.Match(10,Sheets("stackoverflow").Range("H:H"), 0)
```

But when I have it stored as a variable instead, not working.

```
WorksheetFunction.Match(variable,Sheets("stackoverflow").Range("H:H"), 0)
```

and in immediate window when I do ?variable, `variable = '10'`

Comment: what is your variable declared as?

Comment: Not declared, just its `variable = "10"`

Comment: Explicitly declare your variables and also use [`Option Explicit`](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) on all written. This is best practice to force variable declaration. So `Dim variable as Long` (or `Double` or whatever needed) and then `variable = 10`

Comment: declare it as a double and use `Variable = 10` without the quotes.  You are trying to match a string to a list of numbers.  they do not match.

Comment: imho, **never** use WorksheetFunction.Match(...). **Always** use application.Match(...) and return the result to a variant type var. You can test the variant with Iserror().